# Db Structure Issue with EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have been messing around with Entity Framework code first for the last while trying to see what I can do with it.
One scenario I tested out was trying to duplicate the following DB schema:

Tables:

- Person
- Player
- Manager

[image]

Person table holds basic data name,age etc.

Player table only holds information related to a player: currentclubId, positionId etc
The players basic details would be provided through a 1:1 relationship with the Person table on the Player Id and the PersonId.

Manager table is very similar to player table holds a 1:1 relationship with Person Table on the Manager Id and the person Id.

The idea behind this schema is that a person can be player and a manager throughout their career and I wanted to avoid duplication the basic details.

My issue is that EF Generates the Player Model with a Person Property.

```
public class Player {
    public Person Person {get;set;}
    .....    
}
```

Therefore to get the Players first name you must call Player.Person.FirstName.
This flow was fine for the beginning but I'm starting to see a performance issue with the Player and Manager queries as they have to fetch from two tables.

Is there any way I can refactor this schema to improve the performance while not violating the requirements?

Comment: Take only the data what you need?
You can include related entities or not.

Comment: Make new class that inherits the Player and add new properties.  You can add a link to parent but you then have to set the link when you add a new Player

Comment: @Sami the reason for the relationship is that a player could be a player or a manager or both in the lifetime of his career. My thoughts on refactoring would be to create a history table and in there assign whether the person was a player or manager on the team in a column rather than the current version

Answer (score 1):

Based on the schema in the diagram you provided i'd expect something like ...

```
public class Person
{   
   [Key]
   public int PersonId {get;set;}

   [ForeignKey("Player")]
   public int player {get;set;} // make this int? if a person can optionally be a player

   public virtual Player Player {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

You'd then repeat this property model for the manager properties on the person object.
Having then done this, when querying the db you should use .`Include()` to avoid recursive subqueries back to the db in a "lazy loading situation".

For example:

```
var allJoes = Db.Persons
   .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Joe"))
   .Include(p => p.Player)
   .Include(p => p.Manager);
```

You can optionally then add sub selection to pull only the fields you need from that data from the db.

```
var joePieces = allJoes
    .Select(j => new { j.Name, j.Player.PlayerId, j.Manager.ManagerId });
```

With the final result being the execution from ...

```
var results = joePieces.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting each class in a separate table, there always would be 3 tables. So, in any query, you would have a `join` statement which causes the performance issue you mentioned. And, actually, the domain you defined, doesn't need separation in tables. They are just ONE object with some small differences. So it's a good idea to merge tables to one, and avoid `join` queries. To do that, you have some options:

1. Using inheritance: Make `Player` and `Manager` inherit from `Person` and use TBH approach.
2. Using ComplexType: Make `Player` and `Manager` complex types (EF would see them just like an `int`, `string`, `enum`, etc).

In both cases you would have just one table for all 3 types; and there wouldn't be `join` at all.

Comment: I don't think having a join in a SQL statement is in itself a performance issue which is why I suspect they are just pulling the Person row (or a collection) then crawling as they loop through the set, resulting in lazy loading.

Comment: Absolutely correct. The answer is based on information question provided. By that information, the only thing I can guess is `join` and iterating on a object and lazy-loading relations, is so far. Don't you think? . BTW, the domain (as defined in question), isn't complex enough to having 3 tables here. So, avoiding a not necessary `join` seems a great idea.

Comment: Remvoing the need for a Join and subtyping person does seem like a good idea but I have often found that inheritance in EF can be problematic if not done right. Given the nature of the OP's problem I would not advise him to take on advanced concepts like entity inheritance at this time although I would admit that such approach would likely be the superior final solution.

Comment: fair enough. they can completely miss the domain :)

Comment: @Javad_Amiry the TBH approach would mean you have duplicate records if you have a person who was a player and a manager i.e. Fname Lname would be repeated for each type.